# htaccess appends parameters to error pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a small translation system and works fine. When user clicks on the language the website redirects to /en or /pt.
I also have some custom rules on my htaccess file.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule     ^send-email$        send-msg-ajax.php [NC]
RewriteRule     ^cv$                docs/cv.pdf [NC]
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-z_-]+)$     index.php?lng=$1 [QSA,L]


#custom error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Everything works fine but 403 error appends the parameter lng to the url.

```
example.local/imgs/?lng=imgs
```

How can i make this whithout the ?lng=imgs?

thanks in advance!

**Update**

when i write like

```
example.local/imgs
```

htaccess appends the parameter
but when i write like this

```
example.local/imgs/
```

the error page is shown without appeding parameters

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is here

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Exclude certain directories from RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/imgs
# Exclude error pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error\.php
# Custom rules
RewriteRule     ^send-email$        send-msg-ajax.php [NC]
RewriteRule     ^cv$                docs/cv.pdf [NC]

# Language rewrite
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-z_-]+)$     index.php?lng=$1 [QSA,L]

# Custom error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Have it like this:

```bash
#custom error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule     ^send-email$        send-msg-ajax.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^cv$                docs/cv.pdf [NC,L]

# except for real files and directories rewrite all requests
# to index.php with lng as query parameter containing URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ^([a-zA-z_-]+)$     index.php?lng=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this rule

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Add a RewriteCond to exclude the "lng" parameter for error documents
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-z_-]+)$ index.php?lng=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^send-email$ send-msg-ajax.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^cv$ docs/cv.pdf [NC]

# Custom error pages
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

I have added a RewriteCond condition to check if the requested file doesn't exist 
(using %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f). This condition ensures that the "lng" parameter won't be appended to the URL for error documents, such as the 403 error page.